# get number of occurrences between two columns same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, count

I have a problem on how to fetch the number of occurrences of a value in between two columns in MySQL.

```
id1 col1 col2
2    5      3
3    3      4
4    2      1
5    1      3
6    null   2
```

How am I able to get the number of occurences between the two columns like the following?

```
value     occurrence
3                3
1                2
2                2
4                1
5                1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `union all` the columns and then apply a `count` aggregate function:

```
SELECT   val, COUNT(*) AS occurrence
FROM     (SELECT col1 AS val
          FROM   mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT col2 AS val
          FROM   mytable) x
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been trying and trying, until this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the actual data (number of rows per value) pre-aggregating might be more efficient, simply try it out:

```
SELECT   val, SUM(occurrence) AS occurrence
FROM     (SELECT col1 AS val, COUNT(*) AS occurrence
          FROM   mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT col2 AS val, COUNT(*) AS occurrence
          FROM   mytable) x
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```